# operating systems main memory fragmentation

Tags: memory, operating-system, virtual, storage

Suppose a small computer system has 4 MB of main memory. The system manages it in fixed sized frames. A frames table maintains the status of each frame in memory. How large (how many byte) should a frame be? You have a choice of one of the following: 1K, 5K, or 10K bytes. Which of these choices will minimize the total space wasted by processes due to fragmentation and frames table storage?

Assume the following: On the average, 10 processes will reside in memory. The average amount of wasted space will be 1/2 frame for each process.
The frames table must have one entry for each frame. Each entry requires 10 bytes.

---

Here is my answer:

1K would minimize the fragmentation, as known small size leads to big tables but smaller wasted space.

10 processes ~ 1/2 frame wasted on each.

---

Am I on the right track?

Comment: I doubt there is no specific way to determine optimal  page size for a OS. it should depend on various architectural issue. such as TLB, pae table size etc. For example if you have a big TLB in your processor then you can use a small page size efficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are. I agree with you that on a system such as this, the smallest size makes the most sense. However, for example, if you take the situation of x86-64, where the options are 4kb, 2MB, 1GB. Considering modern memory sizes of approximation 4GB, obviously 1GB makes no sense, but because most programs nowadays contain quite a bit of compiled code, or in the case of interpreted and VM languages, all of the code of the VM, 2 MB pages make the most sense. In other words, to determine these things, you have to think about the average memory usage of a program in this system, the number of programs, and most importantly, the ration of average fragmentation to page table size. Because while a small memory size like that benefits from the low fragmentation, 4kb pages on 4GB of memory is a very large page table. *Very* large.